# Deleted folder in encrypted home but did not free any space

Tags: ecryptfs

I have this problem: I used ecryptfs to recover my home folder, which I use as storage for things I rarely use (old photos and videos, games, etc.). It was nearly full, so I sent a 20 GB folder to the Recycle Bin, but no space was freed and the Recycle Bin stays empty. What to do?

Comment: had similar situation today; though several minutes later the free space seemed to increase somewhat out of the blue

Answer (score 0):

When using ecryptfs you'll have the same file *appear* twice (don't worry, it will only exists once).
However, in your case, my guess is that only the file has been marked as deleted (e.g. moved to the trash bin), but not the container - where the file (really) lies.

To delete the container, too, start the terminal and navigate to the folder you deleted the folder in. Type

```
ls -lah
```

and you'll probably see a folder that will have the same name as the other one, but starting with a ".", and ending in _encfs. This is the folder you want to delete, which you can do with

```
rm -rf <foldername>
```

but only AFTER you have unmounted the folder.

Comment: I did ls -lah but the folder I deleted didn't appear. The folder appears twice only if I use the command ecryptfs-recover-private twice, otherwise not.

Comment: Can you go up in the folder tree, and do ls -lahR then (the encrypted folder has to be somewhere - you can tell by it having many files with filenames that appear to be gibberish)? And by "appears twice" I mean that the folder should appear, well, as the folder and as the encrypted container.

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain the situation in depth. When I run ecryptfs-recover-private I get a folder in /tmp which looks like "ecryptfs.wsWs87jl" or similar. Inside is the content of my home folder from three Ubuntu installations or so back, which otherwise is a separate, inaccessible volume. In /tmp/ecryptfs.[something] is the decripted content, and that is where I need to find what happened to the folder I sent to the Recycle Bin.

Comment: Ah, thanks - I did get that wrong. So - to make sure - your problem is that you "lost" the folder? You tried to move it to the trash, but it basically never "arrived", but you cannot see it either?
In that case - go into the decrypted folder in /tmp and start a search of your missing files, with
    find . -name "*somefilenamehere*"
That should give you some information on where the folder has "hidden"

Comment: No luck. I had actually thought of that, only I used the Nautilus search option. I am starting to doubt my sanity.

Comment: Have you retried that using the find command? The nautilus search does not list "hidden" entries - so if you use it, make sure that hidden files are folders are shown first (e.g. by hitting <ctrl>h), or, to make absolutely sure that you'll not miss anything, by using the find command as shown.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, mate! I had forgotten this tread. :) I think I somewhat solved this problem, or I got a new HDD, something like that. Cheers!